# Android App Icon and Name appears multiple times in app

Tags: java, android, admob

My app's screen looks like [this Screenshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxuI5bL-DVqDSVZHNWM0YmZ5ekU/edit).

As you can see I made an App with ads (admob), but there is a bug, I cant fix.

Code:

```
private AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    //create adView

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="....."
    ads:testDevices="....." >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I got no error message in logcat and the app didnt crash. Hope you can help!
I already reboot my phone and restarted eclipse.

EDIT: Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.stefan.game"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.stefan.game.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can u post more informations? is this the full layout xml ?
//Ist das der Vollständige Code? zumindest was die xml angeht.. ? sehr //verwirrend..

Comment: That is the full xml // hi du kannst ja deutsch reden. Ja das ist die ganze layout datei

Comment: can u show me the manifest.xml ? and activity_fullscreen is the given layout? 
//ja hab an der werbung gesehn dass du deutsch bist =) sieht zwar alles richtig aus aber hier nochmal ein tut.. 

btw. here is an tutorial  http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Advertisements-to-Your-Android-Applications-Using-Admob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try a clean build. IT could be that you are getting the wrong resource ids being applied.

Otherwise, try removing the theme attributes for your app and your activity. If the layout XML you provided above is the full XML then I think you have misconfigured the theme such that you either have a list or repeating background that is being incorporated into your activity layout.

Comment: thx  a lot. I made everything new and now it works. Although I'm pretty sure its the same code.

Comment: Like I thought, you had partially built code. Always try a clean build first, it generally resolves these issues. And please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create an integer to count the instances of your ads.
First see if your integer is superior to 1.

Comment: how can i count the instances of my ads?